# How to programatically get table structure with pyscopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

when I execute the program *application.py* ,I get this error :

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError
ProgrammingError: ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « "/d" »
LINE 1: "/d" carto."BADGES_SFR"
```

(in english "`ProgrammingError: ERREUR:  syntax error at or near  « "/d" » "`) My objective for this program is to get the table structure

this is the following code *application.py* :

```
#!/usr/bin/python 2.7.6
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask,render_template
import psycopg2
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def fihoum():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="carto", user="postgres", password="daed5Aemo", host="192.168.12.54")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM carto.\"BADGES_SFR\"")
    cur.execute("/d carto.\"BADGES_SFR\"")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('hello.html', titre="Données du client BADGES_SFR !",mots=rows)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'), 
            port=int(os.getenv('PORT',5000)),
            debug=True)
```

Comment: Does it run with the cur.execute("SELECT * FROM carto.\"BADGES_SFR\"") line?

Comment: yes it run with  cur.execute("SELECT * FROM carto.\"BADGES_SFR\"")

Comment: Would the cur.execute("\d carto.\"BADGES_SFR\"") solve it as @bakkal suggested it?

Comment: I don't think so, because `\d table_name` is invalid SQL syntax, `ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "\"`

Answer (score 8):

First of all it's `\d <table_name>` (note the backslash `\d` not `/d`), but that's only available in the [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html) interactive terminal

> My [objective] with this program is to get the table structure

You can use the SQL table `information_schema.columns` which carries the information you want

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, is_nullable
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = '<table_name>';

    column_name     |     data_type     | is_nullable 
--------------------+-------------------+-------------
 column_a           | integer           | YES
 column_b           | boolean           | NO
```

Here's a list of the columns available for use: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/infoschema-columns.html

**Snippet**

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='carto', user=..., password=...)

q = """                              
SELECT column_name, data_type, is_nullable
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = %s;
"""

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(q, ('BADGES_SFR',))  # (table_name,) passed as tuple
cur.fetchall()

# Example Output 
[('column_a', 'integer', 'YES'),
 ('column_b', 'boolean', 'NO'),
 ...,
]
```

**Tip for Jinja2/Flask integration:**

Consider using [`psycopg2.extras.DictCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor), it'll make it easier for you to pull the information based on the column name (dict key) in your Flask template, because your'll a have a dict that you can access e.g. using `row['data_type']`, `row['column_name']` etc.

Comment: @ZaafLafalaise Can I ask what exactly worked for you?

Answer (score 5):

If you only need the columns [description](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html):

```python
>>> cur.execute('select * from t')
>>> description = cur.description
>>> print description
(Column(name='record_timestamptz', type_code=1184, display_size=None, internal_size=8, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None),)
>>> columns = description[0]
>>> print columns.name, columns.type_code
record_timestamptz 1184
```

For the data type name cache the [pg_type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-type.html) relation at the application start and make it a dictionary:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

cursor.execute ('select oid, * from pg_type')

pg_type = dict([(t['oid'], t['typname']) for t in cursor.fetchall()])

cursor.execute ('select * from t')

for t in cursor.description:
    print t.name, t.type_code, pg_type[t.type_code]
```